# What are the nicknames for common programming special characters?

Tags: language-agnostic

There are common slang names for period, exclamation mark, and asterisk:  
. "dot" 
! "bang" 
* "star"

but what are the teched-out, one-syllable names for characters like
 
% 
 
&
 
< 

{

[

;

etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[The Internet knows plenty of these](http://ascii-table.com/pronunciation-guide.php) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210124000905/http://ascii-table.com/pronunciation-guide.php))

Or, check [the jargon file](http://catb.org/jargon/html/A/ASCII.html).

Comment: It's kinda fun to refer to !* as "bang-splat" :)

Comment: +1. I still use hashbang when writing shell scripts. But I've always liked the Jargon entry for Yu-Shiang Whole Fish (http://catb.org/jargon/html/Y/Yu-Shiang-Whole-Fish.html) or ɣ.

Answer (score 27):

Here's a few, poetry style:

```
<> !*''#
^"`$$-
!*=@$_
%*<> ~#4
&[]../
|{,,SYSTEM HALTED
```

The poem can be appreciated only by reading it aloud:

```
Waka waka bang splat tick tick hash,
Caret quote back-tick dollar dollar dash,
Bang splat equal at dollar under-score,
Percent splat waka waka tilde number four,
Ampersand bracket bracket dot dot slash,
Vertical-bar curly-bracket comma comma CRASH.
```

Source: http://babek.info/libertybasicfiles/lbnews/nl123/fun.htm

Comment: I regret that I have but one upvote to give to this comment.

Answer (score 9):

The intercal reference manual is the definitive guide:

```
.           spot                    identify 16-bit variable      
:           two-spot                identify 32-bit variable      
,           tail                    identify 16-bit array         
;           hybrid                  identify 32-bit array         
#           mesh                    identify constant             
=           half-mesh                                             
'           spark                   grouper                       
`           backspark                                             
!           wow                     equivalent to spark-spot      
?           what                    unary exlusive OR (ASCII)     
"           rabbit-ears             grouper                       
".          rabbit                  equivalent to ears-spot       
|           spike                                                 
%           double-oh-seven         percentage qualifier          
-           worm                    used with angles              
<           angle                   used with worms               
>           right angle                                           
(           wax                     precedes line label           
)           wane                    follows line label            
[           U turn                                                
]           U turn back                                           
{           embrace                                               
}           bracelet                                              
*           splat                   flags invalid statements      
&           ampersand[5]            unary logical AND             
V           V                       unary logical OR              
            (or book)                                             
V-          bookworm                unary exclusive OR            
            (or universal qualifier)                              
$           big money               unary exclusive OR (ASCII)                            
c|          change                  binary mingle                 
~           sqiggle                 binary select                 
_           flat worm                                             
            overline                indicates "times 1000"        
+           intersection            separates list items          
/           slat                                                  
\           backslat                                              
@           whirlpool                                             
-'         hookworm                                              
^           shark                                                 
            (or simply sharkfin)
```

Comment: I will always and forever upvote any answer having to do with INTERCAL

Comment: +1 also. It is a shame the intercal tag only returns one question. Is nobody else using it in production?

Answer (score 7):

Strive for clarity and don't use slang, but instead use the commonly accepted name of each symbol. Thus,

```
. dot or period
! exclamation point
* asterisk or star
% percent (sometimes mod)
& ampersand
< less than
{ left brace
[ left bracket
; semicolon
```

Comment: +1 for promoting clear concise communication.

Comment: "clear concise communication" depends on the parties doing it. I doubt you'd find anyone on slashdot who didn't know that bang meant "!" (they probably wouldn't know what an explanation point was, though :-). And if you said to me poundsign-exclamationpoint-forwardslash-bin-forwardslash-bash for the first line of a shell script, I'd laugh at your noobie attempts of clear communication - so much better would be hashbangbinbash which every UNIX wannabe should learn :-)

Comment: # 'hash' is universal, octothorp is pretentious, calling it pound confuses Brits

Comment: minus 1 for promoting clear concise communication

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to find the more British-flavored ones, I like the #! (read "crunch bang") as in [CrunchBang Linux](http://crunchbanglinux.org/). And for pure weirdness, I enjoy calling "#" the "octothorpe."

Some other fun ones that I've heard (I'd be hard pressed to source these):

```
= "gets" (when reading C code "int num = 5;" would be "num gets five")
` "quasiquote" (lisp)
#! together are often pronounced "shebang" (consider that a kind of tech-dipthong)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider these extras:

```
! not
@ these (Perl)
$ this (Perl)
: otherwise (ternary operator)
; stop (read as a telegram?)
* anything (regex-esque)
& and
| or
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Tyler McHenry's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010523/what-are-the-nicknames-for-common-programming-special-characters/1010526#1010526) list there is also Jeff's [blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001133.html) which links to the [ASCII](http://www.elsewhere.org/jargon/jargon.html#ASCII) entry in The New Hacker's Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
# = "pound"
```

as in

```
#sand
```

or

```
#puppy
```

Answer (score 0):

@ is pronounced "dog" (собака) in Russian (for the visual picture).

Comment: it's monkey or monkey-tail in a couple of languages

Answer (score 0):

Hehe, when I was a kid, I called the "#" - character (don't laugh!) "eh". And "$" was called "xsssss".